# Why is GC pinning not required in SpanHelpers.IndexOf?

Tags: .net, garbage-collection

Looking at for example [SpanHelpers.IndexOf](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/SpanHelpers.Byte.cs,17) we see multiple [Unsafe.Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.unsafe.add?view=net-6.0) operations. These work with direct memory pointers. In earlier versions of .NET when we worked with pointers we had to ensure Garbage Collector would not move the data, for example by using [fixed statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/fixed-statement).

SpanHelpers is internal, but is called from for example [string.IndexOf](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/String.Searching.cs,40).

Why is this not necessary in SpanHelpers.IndexOf? What prevents GC from moving the byte array/string that is being used by SIMD-operations in IndexOf?

Comment: Pointer arithmetic on an array pointer is safe as long as the result remains inside the array and the results is returned as a managed pointer (`ref byte`). This has been the case since .Net 1.

Comment: I'm struggling to find an exact source for the above, but ECMA-335 Part I Section 12.1.5 does state that some arithmetic is allowed: *"Arithmetic operations upon managed pointers are intended only for use on pointers to elements of the same array. If other uses of arithmetic on managed pointers are made, the behavior is unspecified. [Rationale: Since the memory manager runs asynchronously with respect to programs and updates managed pointers, both the distance between distinct objects and their relative position can change. end rationale]"* Also see Part II Section 14.4